# Connect to websites through my shared hosting account

Tags: linux, open-source, web-server

I’m in country *A* and I want to access a website that blocks visitors from *A* (but allows visitors from country *B*).

#### Technology

I’m looking for a tool/solution that I can install on my shared webhosting account (servers in *B*). I don’t want to use a third-party service.

Caveat: As it’s only shared hosting, I don’t have admin access. I can compile/install only in my home directory (I have SSH access.).

Using dynamic/private ports isn’t possible with my current hoster. But if there is no solution that works without port, please feel free to recommend solutions that need a port.

I don’t have a unique IPv4 IP address. I can add an IPv6 IP address to my domain, though.

#### Features

I’m not sure what kind of solution is possible/appropriate. Proxy? VPN? SSH tunneling? Something else? (I don’t have any experience.)

It should work with using a **graphical browser** (e.g., Firefox).

**Everything on the website** (HTML, files, *Adobe Flash*, JavaScript) should go through my server’s connection, as well as anything I send (e.g., sending a message from a contact form).

All **other traffic** (e.g., SMTP, XMPP) should still go through my own connection.

It should be possible to easily **enable/disable** it.

I want to be the only user. So it should be possible to **restrict access** somehow.

#### Formal requirements

- Everything involved must be **FLOSS**.
- Everything involved must be **self-hosted**, no reliance on any other online service.
- It must run natively on **GNU/Linux**.
- It must not require admin rights (no `sudo`).

Comment: I’m not sure which tag(s) to add. Is [tag:web-server] appropriate? [tag:web-apps] doesn’t seem to be right because it might also be a server-side solution (via SSH).

Comment: So you wish to block only web access to Country A, excluding you?

Comment: @gabrieloliveira: I don’t want to block anything. I’m a mere visitor of a website not under my control, but this site blocks all IPs from specific countries. So I want to use my server (which is hosted in an unblocked country) to access (and use!) this site.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I made this with proxy, but I believe than this site I have to recommend a specific software. I will check what I used when I made this and post a answer.

Comment: Did you consider VPN as a solution?

Comment: @Bernhard: I assume a VPN would take over my whole traffic (instead of only the traffic from my browser), right? Anyway, this would still be a valid solution (as this requirement is only a *should*), if there is a VPN server (?) which can be installed/used on shared hosting, i.e., without admin rights.

Comment: ...or using Tor with `ExitNodes` configuration variable set to country B?

Comment: @DeerHunter: Not if this means that the (HTTP) traffic will be visible to other parties (e.g., people running a Tor exit node). I want to rely only on me (= my Internet provider), my server and the websites I visit.

Comment: @unor, a SSH proxy may be the best solution, but your hosting company will be able to peek at HTTP traffic anyway.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding what you mean by 'shared'. Can you compile things then run them as a limited user? Ask a admin to install things?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I can compile software, yes (as long as it doesn’t require `sudo`, i.e., it doesn’t need to write anything outside of my home directory) (however, I never tried that before, so I don’t know if there are some more limits). Asking the admin to install software is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

However, if you have SSH access, why not just use [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)(if you run windows), or ssh tunneling on your own system to set up a ssh tunnel, and use your web browser through that? It won't need any software on your server side (that you don't have already) and is simple to set up.

Alternately you're basically looking for a web proxy, and one that runs on php - you go to the website, pop in your url, and it passes it through for you.

I've not tried it for pages that need a login, but I've used [glype](http://www.glype.com/) through daveproxy for ages when I needed a site my ISP (accidentally) blocked. If you're running your own instance, you it would be less of an issue since you can trust your proxy. It will work on a rediculously basic shared hosting account I believe.

Comment: I wasn’t aware that a SSH tunnel would work without any additional software and that it would work just like that in browsers. I’ll give it a try. -- Regarding Web proxy: Such a tool sounds good (besides PHP, it could also use Perl, Python, Ruby etc., i.e., anything that is available natively for GNU/Linux), however, Glype in particular doesn’t seem to be FLOSS (it’s only "Free for personal use").

Comment: I've not had experience with anything else in that *class* of software. I do think using ssh tunneling is the smart answer here, if you have ssh access, and a php based web proxy otherwise. If you can *run* software without being a admin I have some more ideas