# VPN client for Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, vpn

I live in a country which some websites are blocked from it, I'm trying `apt install oracle-java8-installer` in Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon Rebecca, it says "Error 403, forbidden".

### Programs I know

- OpenVPN: this I think is the best, I managed to configure a VPN by it but the problem is it doesn't always work, sometimes it succeed to connect, sometimes it doesn't, I'm using VPNBook euro-tcp443 server and I have the latest username-password.
- Tor: the problem with it, it tells you to install its browser, I'm comfortable with Opera, besides when I tried it in Windows it didn't always work (some sites were still blocked).
- ZenMate: it's very powerful, Unfortunately it's a browser extension, you can't run `apt install oracle-java8-installer` in the browser, so it doesn't work with me.
- from [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/connect-to-websites-through-my-shared-hosting-account), I found putty, SSH tunneling and glype.

  - putty and SSH wants the server I want to connect while I want something like ZenMate or Expat Shield in Windows (which just work with a single press, don't need you to tell them the server).
  - glype is itself blocked in my country.
- I also saw [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/program-that-can-easily-setup-a-vpn-server), Softether needs you to tell him the server too, TeamViewer isn't what I want here.
- squid: sorry but I never managed to configure it, the thing is I'm not networks expert, I don't know how to setup HTTP port or proxy port, even IP I rely on "automatic discovery".
- 3proxy: I found .rpm package and used alien to obtain .deb, installed it but when I launch `3proxy --help` in terminal it says : "error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I searched and found a script but it's for Ubuntu 32bit, I have 64bit so I don't think it will work.

### Requirements

So I need a program that:

1. easy to use: just press a button and you can surf any site you like (like Expat Shield in Windows).
2. open-source: while I accept free, I heard some things about free VPN services, I think open-source would be more trusted, right?
3. Linux-compatible: Expat Shield is for Windows only.
4. not a browser extension: because I need to download via `apt`, browser extensions won't work with me.
5. works for someone who doesn't know about networks much or has available resources on how to configure it (resources shouldn't say "put the HTTP port you want" but say "you can find your HTTP port by going to …").

### EDIT

I installed tor with its browser and managed to configure the SOCKS proxy with it, the tor browser said it suceeded but I can't figure out how to tell apt to use its proxy.

I installed tsocks, set the server and server_port(in tsocks.conf) to what I put in network_settings in tor, when I launch `tsocks apt install oracle-java8-installer` it still give the same error message "Error 403 forbidden".

when I try `tsocks firefox` it gives these warnings:

**
(process:4392): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:4392): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:4392): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:4392): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:4392): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised

19:13:49 libtsocks(4392): Malformed configuration pair on line 47 in configuration file, "."**

Comment: you better first figure out what service provider you want to use. tor is a volunteer network we can use for free, but other vpn service are generally paid money by month.

Answer (score 1):

however I believe that Tor It's the right solution for you. What was the matter with Tor? It's fully compatible with Linux systems.
It's not a problem that You prefer Opera instead the customized-Tor-Browser. Tor exposes its service on a local port. You have to set the proxy settings on your favourite browser.
To set apt for working under a proxy, please follow this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)
Have a good day

Comment: setting apt to work under a proxy needs you to know the proxy settings, I may try Tor then

Comment: Try it, I repeat, It's the right way to do what You need. Bye

Comment: Tor browser is configured to use a SOCKS 5 proxy and it worked, however I didn't manage to make apt use Tor

Comment: I searched and installed tsocks but don't know how to configure it(I don't know where I add my proxy settings in /etc/tsocsk.conf) and the way in the link didn't work

Comment: What is the link? You have to set two variables: *server* and *server_port* in the tsocks config file. Then launch *tsocks*. Try this [link](http://memo-linux.com/proxy-socks-apt-get/)

Comment: I changed server and server_port, tried `tsocks apt install oracle-java8-installer`, the same , 403 error forbidden, I tried the last command with tor browser opened

Comment: @niceman Did you read the complete error message? Maybe You forgot some step in the configuration, Have You tried tsocks with other apps?

Answer (score 1):

1. if you want use Tor without Tor browser you can install Tor with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install tor
   ```

   In countries such as Iran, Tor was blocked and you should use bridge:

   https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en

   If you want know how to use it in Ubuntu/Debian go to:

   https://www.torproject.org/projects/obfsproxy.html.en
2. also you can Download kerio-client.deb and install it on your Linux distribution from [here](http://download.kerio.com/dwn/kerio-control-vpnclient-linux.deb)
3. you can install [OpenVPN in linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460871/how-to-setup-openvpn-client)

Comment: kerio is still not like Expat shield, tor and OpenVPN already tried